# Django add a list of other model for cart and product

Tags: django

i am trying to create a shop where users can add products on sale and other users can add them to their cart
i can't figure out how can i make a cart contain multiple products and their quantities.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cart(models.Model):
    #list of products
    #list of quantities
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a model in between and use this as a [**`through=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model. In that model one uses a `ForeignKey` to the `Product`, a `ForeignKey` to the `Cart`, and an `IntegerField` for its quantity:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        related_name='carts',
        through='CartProduct'
    )

class CartProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueField(fields=['product', 'cart'], name='unique_product_cart')
        ]
```

You thus add items to a cart by creating (or updating) the `CartOrder` with the given `product` and `cart`. In case the combination of the cart and the product already exists, you can increase its quantity.

You can furthermore iterate over the `mycart.cardproduct_set.all()` queryset to obtain the quantities, we can for example print the names of the products with its quantities with:

```
mycart = …  # some cart
for cartproduct in mycart.cartproduct_set.select_related('product'):
    print(f'{cartproduct.product.name}: {cartproduct.quantity}')
```